# ASP.Net MVC Routing for fixed URL

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have area `BackOffice`, controller `BrandController` and action `Edit`. I want to route following URL to this action: `/BackOffice/Brand/Act/Manage`

The URL is fixed, none of the elements shall be changeable. How can I do that using MapRoute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `AreaRegistration` class for `BackOffice`:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        null,
        "/BackOffice/Brand/Act/Manage",
        new { controller = "Brand", action = "Edit" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was obvious. I used exactly the same approach, just wrote controller = "BrandController" instead of controller = "Brand". So stupid of me. Thanks a lot !!!